# ¿Puede ingresar mis carpetas css en la carpeta assets de angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Hola todos que tal estoy implementando angular 4 en un proyecto y mi duda es la siguiente que tan viable es ingresar mis carpetas css fonts e img en la carpeta assets de angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es lo recomendable. Pero si tienes CSS y JS también no olvides linkar estás dependencias en el . angular-cli.json